# GetKey in ConfigurationElementCollection from ConfigurationPropertyAttribute?

Tags: c#, configuration, configurationmanager

There are a lot of examples out there that explain how to create your own ConfigurationElementCollection, for instance: [Stackoverflow: How to implement your own ConfigurationElementCollection?](http://How%20to%20implement%20a%20ConfigurationSection%20with%20a%20ConfigurationElementCollection)

One of the functions you'll have to override is GetElementKey:

```
protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
{
  return ((ServiceConfig) element).Port;
}
```

where property Port is defined as follows:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("Port", IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
public int Port 
{
  get { return (int) this["Port"]; }
  set { this["Port"] = value; }
}
```

My configuration has several ConfigurationElementCollections that look very similar. The GetElementKey function is the only function that inhibits the use of a generic ConfigurationElementCollection because of the identifier of the key. The ConfigurationPropertyAttribute already informs me which property is the key.

**Is it possible to get the Key property via the ConfigurationPropertyAttribute?**

Code would be like:

```
public class ConfigCollection<T> : ConfigurationElementCollection where T: ConfigurationElement, new()
{
    protected override Object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        // get the propertyInfo of property that has IsKey = true
        PropertyInfo keyPropertyInfo = ... 
        object keyValue = keyPropertyInfo.GetValue(element);
        return keyValue;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get all the properties of the element and look for the one that has a `ConfigurationPropertyAttribute` with `IsKey == true`:

```
protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
{
    object key = element.GetType()
                        .GetProperties()
                        .Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes<ConfigurationPropertyAttribute>()
                                     .Any(a => a.IsKey))
                        .Select(p => p.GetValue(element))
                        .FirstOrDefault();

    return key;
}
```